# How to make the two way binding in AngularJS Isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
directive('confButton', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                replace: false,
                scope: {
                    modalbtntext: '@',
                    btntext: '@',
                    iconclass: '@',
                    btnclass:'@',
                    callback: '&',
                    disabled: '='


                },
                templateUrl : '/app/scripts/mod/Directives/ConfirmationDirective/ConfrimationDirect.html',
                controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', 'modalService',
                    function ($scope, $element, $attsr, $transclude, modalService) {

                        $scope.open = function () {
                            console.log($scope.disabled);
                            var bodyMessage = '';
                            if ($scope.modalbtntext.toLowerCase() == "edit") {
                                bodyMessage = "Are you sure you want to edit this ?"
                            }
                            else{
                                bodyMessage = 'Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'

                            }
                            var modalOptions = {
                                closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                                actionButtonText: $scope.modalbtntext,
                                headerText: 'Please Confirm your Request',
                                bodyText: bodyMessage
                            };

                            modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                                $scope.callback();
                            });
                        }

                    }]



            }
        });
```

and this is my Tempalte

```
<button class="{{btnclass}}" ng-disabled="{{disabled}}"  ng-click="open()"><i class="{{iconclass}}"></i> {{btntext}} </button>
```

here is the implementation of the directive

```
 <conf-button modalbtntext="Delete"
                             disabled="gridOptions.selectedItems.length == 0" 
                             btntext="Delete Selected" 
                             btnclass="btn btn-default hidden-xs"
                             iconclass ="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                             callback="deleteCity()">

                </conf-button>
```

The point is I want to implement the two way binding in the button .. it's disabled by default as no item is selected .. but when I choose any item it still disabled. how can I achieve the two way binding in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make 2 way binding to work you need to bind it to an **object**. What happens is that you bind the value to a primitive during the expression evaluation so the binding doesn't update.

You can use `$watch` to update a certain value.

```
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.gridOption.selectedItems = [];

 $scope.$watch(function(){
  //Watch for these changes
  return $scope.gridOptions.selectedItems.length == 0;
 }, function(newVal){
  //Change will trigger this callback function with the new value
  $scope.btnDisabled = newVal;
 });
});
```

HTML markup:

```
<conf-button modalbtntext="Delete"
                             disabled="btnDisabled" 
                             btntext="Delete Selected" 
                             btnclass="btn btn-default hidden-xs"
                             iconclass ="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                             callback="deleteCity()">
</conf-button>
```